# Facebook Notification using graph api not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I am trying to send app request notification to multiple friends using Graph api,,here is my code

```
   $apprequest_url="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
                       $user_id .
                       "/apprequests?message='My Message'" .
                       "&data='My Data'&"  .  
                       $app_access_token . "&method=post";

                     $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
```

here $result is giving nothing. It shoud return success message.

I dont want to use

```
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Message',
    link: "http://topperlearning.com",
    picture: "http://mydomain.com/abc.jpg",
    to:userIds,
    title:'TopperLearning.com'
}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);            
    });`
```

because it gives firstly popup then user has to click on Send Request.That is why i am trying graph api.BUt not working.I am trapped just because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Javascript version if you remember to activate frictionless requests.

```
FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    frictionlessRequests: true
  });
```

In the PHP-version you seem to missing **"access_token="** . $app_access_token

You should probably urlencode your data as well.